# Angular 2 Lazy Module and Shared modules singleton

Tags: angular

I am learning angular2's  lazy loading and shared dependencies using [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-modules-di.html) article. I understood that lazy module has a separate dependency tree and it doesn't share the same instance of service with eager module.

When I removed SharedModule import from the imports section of lazy module, the behavior changed and I got singleton service between eager and lazy modules.

As per the documentation in order to reuse same shared service there is more to be done as described in [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-di-tree.html) article . But I could make it work just by removing the import from shared module definition. Can someone explain this behavior

Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4vCW0IlblML5FgCCxArt?p=preview)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //SharedModule   //This is removed
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [LazyComponent]
})
```

Comment: I can explain you. List down all your questions

Comment: My question is why is it working even though I had not followed steps in the other article. i.e I did not import the shared module as .forRoot()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lazy loading doesn't create a separate dependency tree - at least, not in the way you're describing.

As you are probably aware, Angular's dependency injection system is actually a tree of injectors - one for each component in the view hierarchy. When you request a dependency, Angular walks this tree of injectors, starting from the component that's requesting the dependency until it finds the first injector that's able to provide that dependency. 
This gives you a lot of power if you need it, since at any level of the component tree, you can specify a provider for a dependency on the component and have that component get its own instance of that dependency. Furthermore, any children of that component will also share that same instance of the dependency.

That's the basic synopsis of how the hierarchal dependency injection works with respect to components. When it comes to modules, however, things are a bit different. By default, any dependencies provided by an NgModule are added to the root injector, meaning that a single instance of that dependency will be shared by the entire application. The exception to this is if the NgModule is lazy loaded. In that case, the dependencies provided by the lazy loaded module won't be added to the root injector. Instead, those dependencies will be added to the root component of the lazy loaded module (i learned this the hard way - if you have multiple 'root components' of your lazy loaded module, each 'root component' will get its own instance of the dependency).

So, it's still the same basic hierarchy - it's just that eager loaded modules add their dependencies to the root injector, whereas lazy loaded modules add theirs to the root component of their module. In addition, if a lazy loaded module imports an NgModule that also provides dependencies (for eg your SharedModule), those dependencies will also be added to that root component of the module.  (Note that if SharedModule is also eager-loaded, its dependencies will also be added to the root injector - leading to multiple instances of those dependencies being available).

That last point is why you're seeing the behaviour you're seeing. When your lazy module imports SharedModule, SharedModules provided dependencies get added to the root component of the lazy module - leading to duplicate instances of those dependencies.

Comment: Great answer. By the way, from a practical standpoint its worth noting that if the service is always loaded by any eagerly loaded `ngModule` then there is no reason to import it in the lazily loaded one. On the other hand, if you keep state out of your services, then this issue won't affect you at all.

Comment: @AluanHaddad very good point about keeping state out of the services. I mean, sometimes it's unavoidable - you're using the service as a state sharing mechanism between 2 disparate components - but that's more the exception than the rule